# $\sum_{k=1}^\infty f(z^{n_k})$ is analytic

Tags: complex-analysis

> Suppose $f(z)$ is analytic on $D=\{z:|z|<1\}$ with $f(0)=0$. Suppose
>   $\{n_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ are positive integers such that $n_k<n_{k+1}$
>   for all $k$. Show that on $D$ the function $\sum_{k=1}^\infty
> f(z^{n_k})$ is a well-defined analytic function.

I have no idea how to start. The power series seems to be too complicated in order to prove that it converges directly, and the usual tools like the Weierstrass $M$-test don't apply.

Comment: Sure the M test applies! It's enough to show uniform convergence on compact sets. If $K$ is a compact subset of the disk there exists $c$ so $|f(z)|\le c|z|$ for all $z\in K$...

Comment: Not entirely sure if the statement is actually correct.  Consider $f(z) = 2z$, which is analytic on $D$ and $f(0) = 0$.  But surely, $2z + 2z^2 + 2z^3 + \cdots$ do not converge on all the points of $D$.  Perhaps I'm thinking something very wrong...

Comment: No, that is $\frac{2z}{1-z}$, and it does converge on $D$. @chriseur

Comment: Yes, it does converge.  Please disregard comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to know something about analytic functions to solve this problem. Your function is analytic for $|z|<1$ and $f(0)=0$. Fix any $r\in (0,1)$. Let
$M(r)=\max\{|f(z)|:|z|\leq r\}.$ Then by the Schwarz Lemma (see your complex variables textbook),
$$|f(z)|<|z|M(r)/r,$$
when $|z|<r$.
Then $|f(z^{n_k})|\leq |z|^{n_k}M(r)/r\leq M(r)|z|^k,$
So your series converges by comparison with the geometric progression.
As $r$ was arbitrary in $(0,1)$, the series converges in the whole unit disk.

Answer (score 0):

On every closed disk around $0$ of radius $r<1$, $|f(z)|<C_r|z|$ for some $C_r$, and thus $$\left|f\left(z^{n_k}\right)\right|<C_r|z|^{n_k}$$ when $|z|<r$.

So $\sum f\left(z^{n_k}\right)$ is uniformly convergent, and thus analytic in the $D_r=\{z:|z|<r\}$. For any $z_0\in D$, let $r=\frac{1+|z_0|}{2}$. Then $z\in D_r$ and $r<1$, so $\sum f(z^{n_k})$ is analytic at $z_0$.

Comment: In the displayed inequality, you want to say "for large $k$".

Comment: No, I really don't. @zhw I did mean to restrict it for $|z|<r$, however. My point is to prove it for all smaller open disks.

Comment: Do you need to use Schwarz lemma to conclude $|f(z)| < C_r |z|$?